# Storing files on simulator vs actual iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdata, nsfilemanager

Currently I am storing some mp3 files locally on a simulator using the following code to obtain a path..

```
manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    filePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

This storage method works fine on the simulator, but when I examine the actual path in the debugger, it ends up being a path on my macbook where the simulator is storing its data.  Does anyone know if this code will also work on an actual device? Will a different path be generated that is specific to the target device?  Thanks.

Comment: Your code is correct and will work on devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course this code should be fine, `NSFileManager` will manage this for you, on the iPhone device this will resolve to your applications sandbox. It will therefore be a different absolute path, but this should be irrelevant to you.